# npm start しても React アプリケーションに localhost でアクセスできない

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, wsl

## 現象

`npm start`すると、`http://localhost:3000`でアクセスできず、`http://192.168.xxx.xxx:3000`でのみアクセスできる。
(xxx：伏字にしてます。)

## 解決したいこと

数か月前までは、何事もなく`npm start`でlocalhostにアクセスできていたのですが、突然うまくいかなくなったので困惑しています。

どうしたら、今まで通り`http://localhost:3000`でアクセスできるようになるのか、解決策を教えていただきたいです。

## 詳細

`npx create-react-app myapp`として React アプリケーションを作成しました。
作成したアプリケーションのディレクトリに移動し、`npm start`をしました。

すると、アプリケーションが立ち上がります。

ログは正常な感じで出ています。

```sh
Compiled successfully!

You can now view myapp in the browser.

  Local:            http://localhost:3000
  On Your Network:  http://192.168.xxx.xxx:3000

Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use npm run build.

webpack compiled successfully
```

自動でChromeを立ち上がり、`http://localhost:3000`ページを表示しようとするのですが、以下のように開けません。

[image: エラー]

On Your Network の方にアクセスするとうまく表示されます。

[image: 正常]

## 試したこと

### expressでビルドファイルをサーブ

ためしに、expressを用いて React アプリケーションのビルドファイルを`http://localhost:3000`でサーブしてみました。
コードをこれです。

```js
// server.js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));
app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});
app.listen(port);
if (port === 3000) {
  console.log(`Now hosting at "http://localhost:${port}/"`);
}
```

そして、ビルド　→　サーブ。

```sh
$ npm run build
$ node server.js
```

すると`http://localhost:3000`でアプリケーションが立ち上がりました。

[image: server.js]

このことから、`npm start`したときの`localhost`でうまく立ち上げられていなのだろうと思います。

### ping が送れるか試す

送れました。

```sh
$ ping localhost
PING localhost (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.030 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.253 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.042 ms
^C
--- localhost ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2050ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.030/0.108/0.253/0.102 ms
```

### PCの再起動・create-react-appのやり直し

どちらも解決しませんでした。

## 環境

```
wsl: Ubuntu-20.04
node: v16.14.2
npm: 8.5.0
```

一応`create-react-app`のバージョン

```
$ npx create-react-app --version
5.0.1
```

---

## 追記1

別のPCで同様の作業を行いましたが、何事もなかった。

そのため、現象が起きたPC固有の問題である可能性が出てきた。

## 追記2

`npm start`したら、以下のようなログが出ていることに気が付きました。
サーブ時にコンソールがリフレッシュされるので、気づきませんでした。

ログの内容についてまだ調べていません。

```
(node:1064) [DEP_WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_ON_AFTER_SETUP_MIDDLEWARE] DeprecationWarning: 'onAfterSetupMiddleware' option is deprecated. Please use the 'setupMiddlewares' option.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:1064) [DEP_WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_ON_BEFORE_SETUP_MIDDLEWARE] DeprecationWarning: 'onBeforeSetupMiddleware' option is deprecated. Please use the 'setupMiddlewares' option.
```

## 追記3

高速スタートアップが有効であることで、うまくいっていないといった記事が散見されたので、以下のサイトを参考に、高速スタートアップの無効を試してみましたが、変わりありませんでした。

https://office-hack.com/windows/windows10-faststartup-disabled/

## 追記4

Rails アプリケーションはlocalhostにアクセスできる。

[image: rails]

## 追記5

コメントより

```sh
$ cat /etc/hosts | grep localhost
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
```

### 追記６

マルチポストしました。

### 追記７

回答より：https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/88384/47477

C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts　の内容

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
# Added by Docker Desktop
192.168.0.13 host.docker.internal
192.168.0.13 gateway.docker.internal
# To allow the same kube context to work on the host and the container:
127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal
# End of section
```

でした

teratail.com/questions/dwxplo70vprsi7

Comment: `cat /etc/hosts | grep localhost`を実行したときに`127.0.0.1 localhost`の記述はありますか？

Comment: macかwindowsのどちらでしょうか

Comment: @himenon さん 外出中なので、帰ったらやって見ます。返信ありがとうございます

Comment: @takemori_kondo さん OSはWindows10です。返信ありがとうございます

Comment: マルチポストさせていただきました。https://teratail.com/questions/dwxplo70vprsi7

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4885 に書かれている事象が近いのかなと思われました。こちらでは、 `wsl --shutdown` を行った後起動し直すことで直った、という[報告がいくつか](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4885#issuecomment-797168357)あるようです。

Comment: @DEWAKazuyuki-出羽和之 さん コメントありがとうございます。残念ながら私の場合は上手くい来ませんでした。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 一時的な自己解決

あくまで一時的であり本質的には解決していません。

`.env`ファイルで以下のようにポート番号(`3002`)を指定すると、`localhost:3002` ではアクセスできました。`3000`, `3001` ではうまくいきませんでした。

```
PORT=3002
```

よくわかりませんが、いったんlocalhostにアクセスできたので、別質問として建てたいと思います。

様々なご意見をくださった方々、ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

1. windowsのhostsにlocalhostの記載があるかどうか確認してください。
   C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
2. .envで調整する機能があるので、そこのパラメータが想定通りか確認してください
   https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/main/docusaurus/docs/advanced-configuration.md

Comment: １．に関して追記７に追記しました。

Comment: 127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal の記載をコメントアウトしてみてください

Comment: HOST、PORTを共に独自設定して、やってみました。その結果、PORT:3000,3001ではうまくいかず、3002であればうまくいくことが判明しました。

Comment: kubernetes.docker.internal の記載をコメントアウトしてみてください も試してみます。

Comment: 書き換え　→　変わらず　→　さらに再起動　→　変わらずでした

Answer (score 0):

同様の症状が出ていました。
下記のファイルを消すと動いた経験があります

setupProxy.js
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。原因はこの後見つかって、どうやらwslに対してポートフォワーディングの再設定しなければいけなかったみたいです。ポートフォワーディングの設定が古い設定のまま残っていたために今回このような現象が起こったみたいでした。